# substr is cutting off part of the string for no reason. or at least the reason is eluding me

Tags: c++, substr

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line = "";
    string firstName = "";
    string middleName = "";
    string lastName = "";
    ifstream myFile("Ch7_Ex9Data.txt");
    if(myFile.is_open()){
        while( getline (myFile, line) ){
            size_t pos = line.find(" ");
            lastName = line.substr(0, pos);

            size_t index = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
                index = (line.find(" ", index)) + 1;
            }
            index = index - 1;
            firstName = line.substr(line.find(" "), line.find(" "));
            middleName = line.substr(index);
            cout << firstName << endl;
            //cout << firstName << " " << middleName << " " << lastName << endl;
        }
        myFile.close();
    }else{
        cout << "unable to open file" << endl;
    }
   return 0; 
}
```

my text file is set up like this (lastName, firstName, middleName)

```
Miller, Jason Brian
blair, Lisa Maria
Gupta, Anil Kumar
Arora, Sumit Sahil
Saleh, Rhonda Beth
```

however it keeps cutting off the "a" in "Rhonda" but correctly displays the first name for every other person?

when I use a different complier (visual studio 2017) it only prints the first name Jason then I get the error:

Unhandled exception at 0x76F917D2 in testing.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x010FF108.

[image: Click here to see output]

Comment: can you add output?

Comment: `firstName = line.substr(line.find(" "), line.find(" "))` is nonsensical.

Comment: Questions like "it does this, I expect that, why?" need to be accompanied with a [mcve]. In particular the input should have been removed, unless it is really necessary.

Comment: @Evg: How is it nonsensical? it almost works except for the very last name.

Comment: @GOD, it "almost works" by a coincidence. Take a look at what `substr` documentation says about the arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your code. What are you trying in for loop for example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
    index = (line.find(" ", index)) + 1;
}
```

or line

```
firstName = line.substr(line.find(" "), line.find(" "));
```

it stands for: cut substring from line, beginning index is line.find(" ") and number of characters is line.find(" ") which is wrong. Because you must show here the count of characters which must be cut. The documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr

That's why I solved your problem simply by my own:

```
while( getline (myFile, line) ){
    // Miller, Jason Brian
    // Getting Miller 
    lastName = line.substr(0, line.find(" ") - 1); // find(" ") - 1 for removing , symbol
    line = line.substr(lastName.length() + 2); // cut out lastname from line
    firstName = line.substr(0, line.find(" "));
    middleName = line.substr(line.find(" ") + 1); // find(" ") + 1 for remove leading whitespace
    cout << firstName << " " << middleName << " " << lastName << endl;
}
```

Comment: Allow me to suggest cppreference.com as a higher quality reference site than cplusplus.com. in this case https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr

Answer (score 1):

- `substr` is not the right tool for what you are trying to do.
- **Don’t use long ifs**. Instead of `if(myFile.is_open()) {...}` use:

  ```
  if(!myFile) return -1; // error
  ```
- `getline` has a third parameter – **delimiter** – which allows you to specify which  character will stop the extraction. So you can actually ask it to stop when it finds `‘,’`
- To **skip white-spaces** use `ws` function or manipulator:

  ```
  ws( is ); // function
  is >> ws; // manipulator
  ```

**Your fixed program** (assumes the content of file is well formed):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ifstream is{ "Ch7_Ex9Data.txt" };
  if (!is)
    return -1;

  string s;
  while (ws(is), getline(is, s, ',')) // skip the white-spaces, then read up to ','
  {
    cout << "First Name: " << s << endl;

    ws( is ), getline(is, s, ' ');
    cout << "Middle Name: " << s << endl;

    ws(is), getline(is, s, '\n');
    cout << "Last Name: " << s << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++17 solution using a `string_view`:

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

std::string line = "Saleh, Rhonda Beth";
const auto first_space = line.find(' ');
const auto last_space = line.rfind(' ');
std::string_view lastName(line.c_str(), first_space - 1);
std::string_view middleName(line.c_str() + last_space + 1);
std::string_view firstName(line.c_str() + first_space + 1, last_space - first_space - 1);

std::cout << firstName << ' ' << middleName << ' ' << lastName << std::endl;
```